# error occur when I call execvp to run java

Tags: c++, linux, system, execvp

I use `chdir()` to switch the directory, and then use `execvp()` to execute "java Main". I'm sure there is Main.class, but something went wrong. I want to know why.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char buf[80];
    getcwd(buf,sizeof(buf));
    printf("current working directory: %s\n", buf);
    chdir("/home/keane/Judge/temp");
    getcwd(buf,sizeof(buf));
    printf("current working directory: %s\n", buf);
    char *array[3];
    array[0] = "java";
    array[1] = "Main";
    array[2] = NULL;
    execvp("java", array);
    return 0;
}
```

the error is `could not find the main class` , and I can run `java Main` in that directory.

What drives me crazy is that I can't use `system("java Main")`, and the error is that `Error: Could not find or load main class Main`, and it's just like this on my computer

update:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
    chdir("/home/keane/Judge/temp");
    system("pwd");
    system("ls");
    system("java Main");
    return 0;
}
```

the output on console is:

```
/home/keane/Judge/temp
1.out  3.out  5.out   Main.class  stdout_spj.txt
2.out  4.out  ce.txt  Main.java
Error: Could not find or load the main class Main
```

my final solution is to reboot the computer and add `-cp .` to the java command.
althought I don't why is necessary.
thanks everyone!

Comment: Isn't `java` supposed to get a `.jar` file containing that `Main` class as well? I am no Java expert, so please ignore my ignorance if I don't know exactly. But please put the error message to your quesiton as well, without it's hard to diagnose what's going on for everyone.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no, `java Main` would run `main` method of `Main.class` containing fully qualified class name `Main`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala And where is the .jar or whatever taken from by default?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ there are no "default jars"... whatever that means. `Main.class` needs to be a file in that directory. `javac Main.java; java Main`

Comment: Please copy the entire error message into the question and verify that `cd /home/keane/Judge/temp; ls Main.class` you indeed see it in that directory.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala OK, I suspected such, so one of the possible reasons that the program code fails, is that the exacutable from above runs in a different directory than the OP expects it does. That's a common error seen when unexperienced users run from an IDE, and complain they can't open text files placed at the project file level.

Comment: I update the description  @AnttiHaapala

Comment: @zxCoder ok, clearer now. Then I suspect the java in your shell is different from that java. If you enter `which java` in your shell and do `system("which java")` do they both point to the same executable?

Comment: You could also try adding that `-cp .` suggested by Peter, though the similar has always worked for me without.

Comment: I'm very puzzled. I tried to add '- cp .' before, but failed. But just now I rebooted the computer and tried it again, and it succeeded...
I don't know why it was necessary, but it is success for me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as intended on my system, maybe you need to add `-cp .` to your java call.

EDIT: to elaborate: `-cp` (for *classpath*) tells java where to look for user provided `.class` files. This does not necessarily include the current working directory by default.

Comment: The problem is on the code, maybe sometimes it can work but it shouldn't because how the function `execvp` works.

Comment: @cdecompilador: Your answer makes no sense at all, why would the output not be visible just because the current process is replaced by `java`?

Comment: Thats how the function `execvp` works as far as I undestanded, it shadows the process but its non-blocking

Comment: @cdecompilador: That's not true, it completely _replaces_ the current process. Any code after the _execvp_ call will never be executed if _execvp_ succeeds. See e.g. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html

Answer (score 0):

The execution of ***execvp()*** is non-blocking and takes ownership of the caller, that means that when it starts if the program ends too quickly you will never be able to see the result, to solve this I use fork(). The wait is just to avoid using sleep as I used at the begining. Its all in c.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char buf[80];
    getcwd(buf,sizeof(buf));
    printf("current working directory: %s\n", buf);
    chdir("/home/");
    getcwd(buf,sizeof(buf));
    printf("current working directory: %s\n", buf);
    char *array[3] = {"java", "Main", NULL};
    if(fork() == 0) {
        if(execvp("java", array) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error spawning command: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
    } else {
        printf("Command spawned\n");
        wait(NULL); // Wait to the forked process to end (avoid using sleep)
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm very confused. I copied your code completely, only modified the directory of the Main.class. But the error is still occur. I don't know if it's my java environment problem, but I can run "java Main" in this path.

Comment: It shows you some kind of error? If the command fails it should show something similar to `Error spawning command: <reason>`. This works in my system

Comment: no, just show "error: Could not found the main class."

Comment: I changed the chdir() function because to make it work on my system

Comment: I know, I change the parameter to the path of my Main.class

Comment: Lets make a little test first if instead of the `java` command you put `g++ -v` in the `execvp()` function to ensure it works correctly, because it seems to be a problem on the path

Comment: I tried some other commands in the execvp (), maybe I can say that everything is ok except `java`

Comment: A couple comments ago you said that the error was `error: Could not found the main class`. Maybe in the path you put in chdir() threre is no Main class or try appending the `.class` to the command invocation. Its an weird error.

Comment: More bizarrely, I can execute `javac Main.java` in execvp(), but the `java` can't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221370/discussion-between-cdecompilador-and-zxcoder).